# how to use jwplatform api using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, jwplayer

I am going to create search api for Android and iOS developers.
Our client have setup a lambda function in AWS. 
Now we need to fetch data using jwplatform Api based on search keyword passed as parameter. For this, I have to install jwplatform module in Lambda function or upload zip file of code with dependencies. So that i want to run python script locally and after getting appropriate result i will upload zip in AWS Lambda.
I want to use the videos/list (jwplatform Api) class to search the video library using python but i don't know much about Python. So i want to know how to run python script? and where should i put the pyhton script ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am succeed to install jwplatform module locally.
Steps are as follows:
1. Open command line
2. Type 'python' on command line
3. Type command 'pip install jwplatform'
4. Now, you can use jwplatform api.

Above command added module jwplatform in python locally
But my another challenge is to install jwplatform in AWS Lambda.

After research i am succeed to install module in AWS Lambda. I have bundled module and code in a directory then create zip of bundle and upload it in AWS Lambda. This will install module(jwplatform) in AWS Lambda.

Answer (score 1):

There are a handful of useful Python script examples here: https://github.com/jwplayer/jwplatform-py